# Set CharField to RTL in Django Admin site

Tags: django

The frontend of my Django site is in Persian language which is RTL and everything is ok except that the `CharField` model fields are in LTR direction when edited in the Admin site.

Here's my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published'))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, allow_unicode=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    lead = RichTextField()
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Featured Post')

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    featured = FeaturedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-published_on',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I know I can set the site's language to Persian and solve this issue but I don't want to because the Persian translation of Django is dull.

Another solution is to use one of available Rich Text editors (tinymce or ckeditor) but those are overkill for a `CharField` field.

I also tried custom admin form like this:

```
class PostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'author', 'lead', 'body', 'status', 'is_featured']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'dir': 'rtl'})}


@admin.register(Post, PostAdminForm)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'created_on', 'published_on', 'status', 'is_featured')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created_on', 'published_on', 'is_featured')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'published_on'
    ordering = ('status', 'created_on', 'published_on')
```

But it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'abstract'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer provided by Nathan was partially correct, I did my own research and found that the correct way is this:

```
class CustomPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'lead', 'body']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'dir': 'rtl', 'class': 'vTextField'})}
```

and then:

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomPostForm
```

What surprises me is that the above code removed `vTextField` class from the `input` field so I had to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

In your `admin.py` file for your app, you can create a custom form for your model. I don't know your model so I will use general names for this as an example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app_name.models import *
from django import forms
class CustomAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      fields = ['mycharfield']
      widgets = {'mycharfield':forms.TextInput(attrs={'dir':'rtl'})}

admin.site.register(MyModel,CustomAdminForm)
```

This should make the `mycharfield` text input render as being RTL on the admin page for the `MyModel` form. The line `widgets = {'mycharfield':forms.TextInput(attrs={'dir':'rtl'})}` will change the text input widget's `dir` attribute to the `rtl` value. If you have more than one `CharField` in your model and want RTL for all of them simply add each field to the `fields` attribute in the form and do the same thing with the `widget` attribute for each field.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post with the model and the error I receive.